# Filebeat not harvesting logs with autodiscover

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-helm, filebeat

I'm having an issue with Filebeat on an environment which suddenly stopped sending logs to elasticsearch. On both environments we have the same setup but on this one it just stopped.. Filebeat, ElasticSearch and Kibana version 7.15.0 all helm deployments
/var/lib/docker/containers/ is empty on the filebeat container but so is in the other working environment..

Filebeat logs:

```
2022-07-02T16:56:12.731Z        DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:139      Run input
2022-07-02T16:56:12.731Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:215        Start next scan {"input_id": "31e0e6d8-e599-453a-a8d0-69afdf5b52d6"}
2022-07-02T16:56:12.731Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:279        input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0        {"input_id": "31e0e6d8-e599-453a-a8d0-69afdf5b52d6"}
2022-07-02T16:56:12.976Z        DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:139      Run input
2022-07-02T16:56:12.976Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:215        Start next scan {"input_id": "89b55ab8-8fb3-49c4-9d9e-2372c956cf49"}
2022-07-02T16:56:12.977Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:279        input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0        {"input_id": "89b55ab8-8fb3-49c4-9d9e-2372c956cf49"}
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:139      Run input
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:139      Run input
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:139      Run input
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:215        Start next scan {"input_id": "ac5b2c6d-189a-420a-bb00-f9d9e6d5aef7"}
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:215        Start next scan {"input_id": "be885467-72ea-44c1-bdce-cdd91fb03e79"}
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:215        Start next scan {"input_id": "1fa30d44-77e8-42ec-8d22-55abd4f8f60b"}
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:139      Run input
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:279        input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0        {"input_id": "ac5b2c6d-189a-420a-bb00-f9d9e6d5aef7"}
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:279        input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0        {"input_id": "1fa30d44-77e8-42ec-8d22-55abd4f8f60b"}
2022-07-02T16:56:13.074Z        DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:279        input states cleaned up. Before: 0, After: 0, Pending: 0        {"input_id": "be885467-72ea-44c1-bdce-cdd91fb03e79"}
```

Inside the filebeat container:

```
ls data/registry/filebeat
log.json
meta.json


cat logs/filebeat
2022-07-02T17:37:30.639Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:665    Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Data path: [/usr/share/filebeat/data] Logs path: [/usr/share/filebeat/logs]
2022-07-02T17:37:30.640Z        DEBUG   [beat]  instance/beat.go:723    Beat metadata path: /usr/share/filebeat/data/meta.json
2022-07-02T17:37:30.640Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:673    Beat ID: b0e19db9-df61-4eec-9a95-1cd5ef653718
2022-07-02T17:37:30.640Z        INFO    [index-management]      idxmgmt/std.go:184      Set output.elasticsearch.index to 'filebeat-7.15.0' as ILM is enabled.
2022-07-02T17:37:30.641Z        INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:100   elasticsearch url: http://elasticsearch.logging:9200
2022-07-02T17:37:30.740Z        DEBUG   [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:249   ES Ping(url=http://elasticsearch.logging:9200)
2022-07-02T17:37:30.742Z        DEBUG   [esclientleg]   transport/logging.go:41 Completed dialing successfully  {"network": "tcp", "address": "elasticsearch.logging:9200"}
2022-07-02T17:37:30.743Z        DEBUG   [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:272   Ping status code: 200
2022-07-02T17:37:30.743Z        INFO    [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:273   Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.15.0
2022-07-02T17:37:30.743Z        DEBUG   [esclientleg]   eslegclient/connection.go:328   GET http://elasticsearch.logging:9200/_license?human=false  <nil>

cat data/meta.json
{"uuid":"b0e19db9-df61-4eec-9a95-1cd5ef653718","first_start":"2022-05-29T00:10:26.137238912Z"}

ls data/registry/filebeat
log.json
meta.json

cat data/registry/filebeat/log.json

cat data/registry/filebeat/meta.json
{"version":"1"}

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 1e66a1c066aa10de73834586c605c7adf71b2c652498b0de7a9d94b44633f919
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.0.4.120/32
    cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.0.4.120/32
    co.elastic.logs/enabled: "false"
    configChecksum: 9e8011c4cd9f9bf36cafe98af8e7862345164b1c11f062f4ab9a67492248076
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: "2022-04-14T16:22:07+03:00"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-07-01T13:53:29Z"
  generateName: filebeat-filebeat-
  labels:
    app: filebeat-filebeat
    chart: filebeat-7.15.0
    controller-revision-hash: 79bdd78b56
    heritage: Helm
    pod-template-generation: "21"
    release: filebeat
  name: filebeat-filebeat-95l2d
  namespace: logging
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: DaemonSet
    name: filebeat-filebeat
    uid: 343f6f76-ffde-11e9-bf3f-42010a9c01ac
  resourceVersion: "582889515"
  uid: 916d7dc9-f4b2-498a-9963-91213f568560
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchFields:
          - key: metadata.name
            operator: In
            values:
            - ..mynode
  containers:
  - args:
    - -e
    - -E
    - http.enabled=true
    env:
    - name: POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    - name: NODE_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
      value: elasticsearch.logging:9200
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:7.15.0
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          #!/usr/bin/env bash -e
          curl --fail 127.0.0.1:5066
      failureThreshold: 3
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    name: filebeat
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          #!/usr/bin/env bash -e
          filebeat test output
      failureThreshold: 3
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 200Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 50m
        memory: 50Mi
    securityContext:
      privileged: false
      runAsUser: 0
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      name: filebeat-config
      readOnly: true
      subPath: filebeat.yml
    - mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/my_ilm_policy.json
      name: filebeat-config
      readOnly: true
      subPath: my_ilm_policy.json
    - mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
      name: data
    - mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
      name: varlibdockercontainers
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/log
      name: varlog
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      name: varrundockersock
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-2gvbn
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: ..mynode
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: filebeat-filebeat
  serviceAccountName: filebeat-filebeat
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure
    operator: Exists
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable
    operator: Exists
  volumes:
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 384
      name: filebeat-filebeat-daemonset-config
    name: filebeat-config
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/filebeat-filebeat-logging-data
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: data
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      type: ""
    name: varlibdockercontainers
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/log
      type: ""
    name: varlog
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
      type: ""
    name: varrundockersock
  - name: kube-api-access-3axln
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it worked with another configuration posted on elastic.co website:

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      hints.enabled: true
      hints.default_config:
        type: container
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/*-${data.container.id}.log  # CRI path
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover-hints.html

I'm still not sure why this happend suddenly  but it the reason might be a container runtime change for kubernetes on the node but I don't have access to check that